# Can't delete an object in delete_view, in Django

Tags: python-3.x, django-forms, django-views

I'm trying to create a delete view for my product form, my problem is with the submit button, it doesn't delete my object, it just redirects me to previous page.

This a Windows 7 machine, Python 3.7.1, Anaconda 2018.12
I've tried eliminating the line: if request.method == "POST"
And without that line the object is eliminated, so I think the problem is with the if statement or the POST method, but couldn't solve it

```
views.py:

from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, redirect

from .forms import ProductForm, RawProductForm

from .models import Product

def product_delete_view(request, id):
    obj = get_object_or_404(Product, id=id)

    if request.method == "POST":
        obj.delete()        
        return redirect('../')

    context = {
        "object": obj
    }

    return render(request, "products\\product_delete.html", context)





product_delete.html:

{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block try %}
<form action='.' method='POST'>{% csrf_token %}
    <h1>Do you want to delete the product "{{ object.title }}"?</h1>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Yes" /> 
        <a href="../">Cancel</a>
    </p>
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

The idea is that when I click "Yes", the object disappears, but instead I am redirected to the page of the actual object I wanted to delete

Comment: What happens if you use `<form action='.' method='post'>` instead of `method='POST'`?

Comment: It works perfect! Thank you, you solved it